# Add a "frame" of zeros around a matrix in numpy python

Tags: numpy, matrix

I have a matrix of size (456, 456). I would like to make it of size (460, 460) but adding a frame of two zeros all around it.

Here is an example with a smaller matrix. I would like to transform `matrixsmall` into `matrixbig`. What is the best way to do it? The original code operates on lots of data to it would be great to have an efficient solution.  Thank you in advance for your help!

```py
import numpy as np
matrixsmall = np.array([[1,2],[2,1]])
matrixbig = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                      [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0], 
                      [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
                      [0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Look into `numpy.pad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.pad(matrixsmall, (2,2), "constant", constant_values=(0,0))

will do the trick